# Enable cache only for static content using reversed proxy (Nginx + Tomcat)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, tomcat8

I have installed Nginx 1.8.0 that works with a reversed proxy to a Tomcat 8, everything's works perfectly. However, I would like to enable proxy-cache ONLY for images, CSS and js (primarily static content); I would not like to cache any get to the server because the values may change from one request to other.

I found some configuration but still not working for me, do you guys know how to configure it correctly?

I saw this https://serverfault.com/questions/494669/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-to-cache-images post; however is not clear for me that it will cache only static content, seems that it will cache any 200 response.

Thanks a lot...

-- UPDATE --

I have my images (blablasite.com/images), same for js and css; just replace images for js and css

I have something like this

```
server {
listen            80;
    server_name   blablasite.com;

    # add ssl settings
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
listen            443;
    server_name   blablasite.com;
    root              html;
    keepalive_timeout 70;

    client_max_body_size 50m;

    #charset koi8-r;

    ssl_certificate          /blablasite.com-combined.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key      /ssl/blablasite.com.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    #ssl_ciphers              HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HTTP Strict Transport Security
    add_header                Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
    add_header                X-Frame-Options "DENY";

    # OCSP Stapling
    ssl_stapling              on;
    ssl_stapling_verify   on;
    resolver                  8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout          5s;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
        expires    1d;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";

        # boilerplate copied from location /
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    }

    location / {
        if (-f /webapps/blablasite/maintenance_on.html) {
            return 503;
        }

        index index.html index.jsp;

        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    }

    location /login {
        # apply rate limiting
        limit_req zone=login burst=5;

        # boilerplate copied from location /
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    }
```

Comment: can you please post more details, current nginx configuration. Is static content served from same folder (ie `http://examle.com/js/...`, `http://example.com/css/...` and `http://example.com/img/...`)

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the proper solution for media, css and js